# How to make react-datepicker display properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I cannot make the component react-datepicker display properly.

it actually displays like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0reoZ.jpg).

I wish it could display at least like the [documentation for the component does](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker).

I first thought it was a dependency problem, and added all the dependencies the doc says are needed. The result is still the same.

Some stackoverflow questions talked about this and referred to a missing stylesheet. However I imported everything with npm, so that shouldn't be the problem.

My class component looks like this :

```js
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

class Filters extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate : new Date()
    };
    this.handleStartChange = this.handleStartChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleStartChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate : date
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="filters">
          <div id="filterbox">
            <p id="titre">Filtres</p>
            <DatePicker 
              selected={this.state.startDate}
              onChange={this.handleStartChange} />
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default Filters;
```

I apologize in advance if the problem is very obvious, I'm quite new to reactjs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot to import the package css.

From the documentation:

```js
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

Comment: Aaaand such a beginners mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Missed importing this ‍♂️. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import the react-datepicker.css too, not only the package itself.

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

> Below is a simple example of how to use the Datepicker in a React
>   view. You will also need to require the CSS file from this package (or
>   provide your own). The example below shows how to include the CSS from
>   this package if your build system supports requiring CSS files
>   (Webpack is one that does).

Comment: You sir, are right. Thank you. I will accept adesurirey's answer since it came just a few seconds before yours, but I'd accept both if I could.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

you haven't imported their css file.

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```